# If $\int_0^\infty {e^{-\lambda t}f(t){\rm d}t} = 0$ for all $\lambda >0$ then $f=0$ a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am studying a paper in which the author uses something like that:

Let $f$ be a bounded and Lebesgue measurable function. If $$\int_0^\infty {e^{-\lambda t}f(t)\,{\rm d}t} = 0 
\qquad\text{for all} \qquad \lambda \gt0$$ then $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Could you point me to a proof of this theorem? It is very important for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for help, i hope it works without continuity of $f$, becouse in my problem $f$ depends on transition function $P^t$ of right Markov process.

Comment: As Eric pointed out, this is related to the inverse [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform). I didn't want to induce him to delete his answer, as this certainly is a valuable pointer. Off the top of my head, I don't remember the precise conditions for uniqueness, but this pointer should help looking for results.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is pretty easy to prove with Dynkin's multiplicative system theorem:

> **Theorem.** Suppose $H$ is a vector space of bounded measurable functions on some measurable space $X$, which contains the constants and is closed under bounded pointwise convergence of sequences (i.e. if $f_n \in H$, $f_n \to f$ pointwise, and $|f_n| \le C$ for all $n$, then $f \in H$).  Suppose $M \subset H$ is closed under pointwise multiplication, and let $\mathcal{G}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $M$ (i.e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that makes all functions from $M$ measurable).  Then $H$ contains all bounded $\mathcal{G}$-measurable functions.

The statement looks complicated, but the proof is elementary, and can be found, for instance, in Chapter II.8 of [these notes](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/280_09-10/Lecture_Notes/2009-2010-Probability%20Lecture%20Notes.pdf), along with other references.

Now to prove your theorem, take $X = (0,\infty)$ with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  We note it suffices to show $g(t) := e^{-t} f(t) = 0$ a.e.  ($g$ is integrable, which is more convenient.)

Let $H$ be the set of all bounded measurable functions $h$ such that $\int_0^\infty h(t) g(t) dt = 0$.  $H$ is clearly a vector space which contains the constants, and is closed under bounded convergence thanks to the dominated convergence theorem.

Let $M$ be the set of all functions of the form $h(t) = e^{-\lambda t}$, where $\lambda > 0$.  By assumption, $M \subset H$, and $M$ is clearly closed under multiplication.

Finally, consider the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ generated by $M$.  Note that for any $h \in M$ and any open  interval $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$, we have by definition that $h^{-1}((a,b)) \in \mathcal{G}$.  Taking $h(t) = e^{-t}$ and $(a,b) = (e^{-d}, e^{-c})$ we see that $(c,d) \in \mathcal{G}$.  Since $\mathcal{G}$ contains all open intervals it must be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $(0, \infty)$.

So by Dynkin's theorem, $H$ contains all bounded Borel-measurable functions on $(0, \infty)$.  In particular it contains ${g}$!  This means that $\int_0^\infty g(t)^2 dt = 0$, so clearly $g = 0$ a.e.

The multiplicative system theorem is really a functional version of the better known $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, and acts as sort of a measurable-function analogue of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.  I've used it here as sort of an advertisement, since I think the theorem deserves to be more widely known given how useful it can be.

I'll also remark that the proof works just as well if we only assume that $\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t} f(t) dt = 0$ for large values of $\lambda$.  Integer values of $\lambda$ would also suffice.

Comment: thanks Nate, i think it is exactly what i need.. the uniqueness of the Laplace transformation seems to be naturally, but i noticed that the Learch's Theorem need the continuity, and your solution works without this assuption!

Comment: One question: Can we guarantee that $g$ is Borel measurable when $f$ is Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: @Jose27: If $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, then $f$ is a.e. equal to a Borel measurable function.  (Proof: For $f$ an indicator function, this is the definition of the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, so it also holds for simple functions.  Now write $f$ as a limit of a sequence of simple functions.)  So in fact we might as well assume $f$ is Borel measurable from the start.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the result you're looking for is called [Lerch's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchsTheorem.html) - essentially, if two functions have the same Laplace transform (or other linear integral transform) then their difference is a null function; i.e., its integral vanishes.  In your case, one of the two functions is simply the zero function; since its Laplace transform is (trivially) identically zero, then any function whose Laplace transform is also identically zero must differ from it by a null function - or in other words, must *be* a null function itself; it is then (by definition!) zero a.e.

Comment: Sorry if I ask: what exactly are the hypotheses of Lerch's theorem? The information in that link is completely useless: "functions", what is that supposed to mean? The only instances I found by googling require continuity of $f$ and thus don't answer the present question.

Answer (score 1):

Define $$g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, t\mapsto\begin{cases}
               f(t)\ \  \textrm{if} \ \ t\ge0\\
               0\ \ \textrm{otherwise}
            \end{cases}$$
Being $g\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, we have that the function $$F:\{\operatorname{Re}(z)>0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}, z\mapsto\int_\mathbb{R}e^{- 2\pi zt}g(t)\operatorname{d}t$$
is well defined and holomorphic and, by hypothesis, null on $(0,+\infty)$. By the identity principle for holomorphic functions, it follows that $F\equiv0$.
Now, fix $x>0$ and define $$h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}, t\mapsto g(t)e^{- 2\pi xt}.$$
Notice that $h\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and so the Fourier transform of $h$ in $y\in\mathbb{R}$ is $$\hat{h}(y)=\int_\mathbb{R}h(t)e^{- 2\pi i yt}\operatorname{d}t=\int_\mathbb{R}g(t)e^{-2\pi  xt}e^{- 2\pi i yt}\operatorname{d}t=\int_\mathbb{R}g(t)e^{-2\pi (x+iy)t}\operatorname{d}t=F(x+iy)=0.$$
Then, noticing that also $\hat{h}$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ (it is the zero function), by Fourier inversion formula, for almost every $t\in\mathbb{R}$ it holds that:
$$h(t)=\int_\mathbb{R} \hat{h}(y) e^{2\pi iyt}\operatorname{d}y=0.$$
Multiplying both sides of this equation by $e^{2\pi xt}$, we get that $g(t)=0$ for almost every $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Being $f$ equal to $g$ on $[0,+\infty)$, we get the conclusion.