# Spectral Measures: Uniqueness

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider spectral measures:
$$E^{(\prime)}:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{C})\to\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$

Denote their operators by:
$$M^{(\prime)}:=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}E^{(\prime)}(\lambda)$$
Then one has:
$$M=M'\iff E=E'$$

How can I prove this?

Comment: Use the Stone-Weierstraß Theorem and this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111983/borel-measurable-function-is-pointwise-limit-of-a-sequence-of-continuous-functio

Comment: @PhoemueX: You mean building up the whole measurable calculus again? *(Note also that the measure may have unbounded support.)*

Comment: Oh, ok... The unbounded support could be a problem for this argument. Apart from that: The existence of the Borel calculus for a spectral measure should be pretty clear, should it not?

Comment: @PhoemueX: Sure the Borel calculus exists but does equality of the associated operator really imply equality of its spectral measures?

Comment: Someone wants bounty for free: Post any remark as answer! ;)

Comment: Hi, just wondering, from which book are you learning stuff about spectral measure?

Comment: @Cortizol: From my head... :P

Comment: @Cortizol: The problem is there's almost none!

Comment: @Cortizol: I can give you some references anyway; but please open a thread on it. *(E.g. "Spectral Measures: References")*

Comment: @Freeze_S I don't need really reference. I was just wondering. For example, Birman and Solomyak have some nice books about it. I know also that in Rudin (Function Analysis) we can find also some stuff, but not too much.

Comment: @Cortizol: Yep, but sadly all of them have some deficits... :(

Comment: @Cortizol: By the way, do you want the bounty? *(I'd be happy.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S Thanks, but no, I didn't deserve it.

Comment: @Cortizol: It would be my first bounty to award. :) *(For badges!)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I finally found a proof. :D*

Consider the projections:
$$N_\Re:=\frac{1}{2}\{N+N^*\}=\frac{1}{2}\{N'+N'^*\}=:N'_\Re$$
$$N_\Im:=\frac{1}{2i}\{N-N^*\}=\frac{1}{2i}\{N'-N'^*\}=:N'_\Im$$

Their resolvents agree:
$$R_\alpha(z)=(z-N_\alpha)^{-1}=(z-N'_\alpha)^{-1}=R'_\alpha(z)$$

By Stone's formula:
$$E_\alpha(-\infty,\lambda_\alpha]\varphi=\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\int_{-\infty}^{\lambda_\alpha+\delta}\Delta R_\alpha(s\pm i\varepsilon)\varphi\mathrm{d}s\\
=\lim_{\delta\to0^+}\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\int_{-\infty}^{\lambda_\alpha+\delta}\Delta R'_\alpha(s\pm i\varepsilon)\varphi\mathrm{d}s=E'_\alpha(-\infty,\lambda_\alpha]\varphi$$

By construction one has:
$$E^{(\prime)}_\Re(A)=E^{(\prime)}(A\times\mathbb{R})\quad E^{(\prime)}_\Im(B)=E^{(\prime)}(\mathbb{R}\times B)$$

Therefore one obtains:
$$E(-\infty,\lambda]=E\bigg((-\infty,\lambda_\Re]\times\mathbb{R}\bigg)E\bigg(\mathbb{R}\times(-\infty,\lambda_\Im]\bigg)\\
=E'\bigg((-\infty,\lambda_\Re]\times\mathbb{R}\bigg)E'\bigg(\mathbb{R}\times(-\infty,\lambda_\Im]\bigg)=E'(-\infty,\lambda]$$

Concluding the assertion.